# Create a model called inside another model in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, relational-database

I defined a model Phone inside another model User with "Has One" relationship, now I need to create a new Phone model, how to do that within controller?

```
class User extends Eloquent {

public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Phone');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code hasn't defined phone model, it defined the relationship. Create another file with name phone.php and make it extend the eloquent class.
The function you wrote can be used to insert , delete or retrieve all phone records for a particular user. 
The parameter Phone  is the name of the model it will look for when you call    phone(). It expects a 'Phone.php' file with Phone model defined ( a class called 'Phone' extending Eloquent).